Redis Stack Server with the HA setup in the kubernetes
We are using the redis-rejson in the production kubernetes environment with the HA setup using sentinel.now we are planning migrate to redis-stack-server in the production with HA setup.
There are HA Helm chart for the redis https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/dandydev-charts/redis-ha. I have try to update the image from the redis to redis-stack-server but it is not running.
